# Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, multithreading

When i try to run following code example it gives me java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError exception.I have take looked at related question. so they didnt fix my problem.
Anyone can help?

```
public class UnitsSearchExample implements Runnable {
    private Session session;

// Login to server
private void login(){
    // initialize Wialon session
    session.initSession("http://hst-api.wialon.com");
    // trying login
    session.login("wialon_test", "test", new ResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String response) {
            super.onSuccess(response);
            // login succeed
            System.out.println(String.format("Logged successfully. User name is %s", session.getCurrUser().getName()));
            //call search units
            searchUnits();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int errorCode, Throwable throwableError) {
            super.onFailure(errorCode, throwableError);
            // login failed, print error
            System.out.println(Errors.getErrorText(errorCode));
        }
    });
}

private void searchUnits(){
    //Create new search specification
    SearchSpec searchSpec=new SearchSpec();
    //Set items type to search avl_units
    searchSpec.setItemsType(Item.ItemType.avl_unit);
    //Set property name to search
    searchSpec.setPropName("sys_name");
    //Set property value mask to search all units
    searchSpec.setPropValueMask("*");
    //Set sort type by units name
    searchSpec.setSortType("sys_name");
    //Send search by created search specification with items base data flag and from 0 to maximum number
    session.searchItems(searchSpec, 1, Item.dataFlag.base.getValue(), 0, Integer.MAX_VALUE, new SearchResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccessSearch(Item... items) {
            super.onSuccessSearch(items);
            // Search succeed
            System.out.println("Search items is successful");
            printUnitsNames(items);
            logout();
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(int errorCode, Throwable throwableError) {
            super.onFailure(errorCode, throwableError);
            // search item failed, print error
            System.out.println(Errors.getErrorText(errorCode));
            logout();
        }
    });
}

private void printUnitsNames(Item... items){
    if (items!=null && items.length>0) {
        System.out.println(String.format("%d units found\r\nPrinting their names...", items.length));
        //Print items names
        for (Item item : items)
            System.out.println(String.format("\t%s", item.getName()));
    }
}
// Logout
private void logout(){
    session.logout(new ResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String response) {
            super.onSuccess(response);
            // logout succeed
            System.out.println("Logout successfully");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int errorCode, Throwable throwableError) {
            super.onFailure(errorCode, throwableError);
            // logout failed, print error
            System.out.println(Errors.getErrorText(errorCode));
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void run() {
    // get instance of current Session
    session=Session.getInstance();
    login();
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    new Thread(new UnitsSearchExample()).start();
}
}
```

**Stack Trace**

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/JsonElement at wialonTest.UnitsSearchExample.run(UnitsSearchExample.java:110) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gson.JsonElement at 
java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366) at 
java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method atjava.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:3 at 
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java atsun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadCla –
```

Comment: Which class?  Print the whole stack trace.

Comment: SearchSpec ???????????????

Comment: I wanted to use the code example in http://sdk.wialon.com/wiki/en/sidebar/javaapi/codesamples/search

Comment: ok, but we still need the whole stack trace..

Comment: A `NoClassDefFoundError` can’t be spotted by looking at the Java source code as it indicates that something has broken on the way *after* compiling to the application’s runtime environment. Usually the class path used for compiling doesn’t match the runtime class path. You have to focus on that.

Comment: do you have the gson.jar in the classpath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set in your classpath that package.

You can get it here:

https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/downloads/list

To put in you classpath you have to put it in you build path if you are developing with eclise (Project - Properties - java build path - libraries -add external JAR - select the jar).

This should fix that problem...

EDIT: you have a dependencie missing problem. To fix this you should use some dependencie manager like maven or add each missing jar to your classpath, to do this find the jars in the internet and redo adding them to the project in eclipse.

To find them in internet try googling:

"java maven <.....>"

As example, java maven org/apache/http/client/methods/ send you to*:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.1.1

There you can, clicking 'download jar' get the  jar AND all the Jars that it depends on (in the same page, scroll down and there are). Download them, add to puild path and its done...

Hard work? yeah, thats why is prefereable to use some manager like maven. With maven you can copy&paste the < dependency>..<\dependency> in your pom.xml file and it will download all necesary jars for given dependencie...

* You can, also, find the package in maker's page and he can give you a package with all required dependences. But for sure: you'll have more of that exceptions so I send you to maven repositories in which are almost all the jars you could need.

Comment: Now it gives another error like that:
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpUriRequest